# Pre populate selected options in select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to pre populate selected options using 'val', but I'm getting only one option as preselected in the options.
[JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/wzshpjb1/)

```
<select name="question_tags[]" id="question_tags" class="select2_tags" multiple="multiple">
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.select2_tags').select2({
                placeholder:"Select",
                data : ["Data Structure", "DBMS", "OS"]

            }).select2('val', ["OS", "DBMS"]);
        });
```

I'm using select2 v4.06

I explored it, and found the functionalities implemented for the previous version of select2, which is now deprecated in recent versions
[Existing solutions JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/2ftk5c8z/)

The solution in the link is not working for current version of select2,
[How to pre-select values in select2 multi select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730167/how-to-pre-select-values-in-select2-multi-select/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above all you need to use `multiple:true` option to make it multiselect, then you need to use `SelectElement.val([1,2,3])` and then `SelectElement.trigger('change')` to notify any JS Components about the value has changed. [**`Docs`**](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options) Reference

See demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var select2 = $('.select2_tags').select2({
    placeholder: "Select",
    width: '500px',
    data: ["Data Structure", "DBMS", "OS"],
    multiple: true,
  })
  select2.val(["DBMS", "OS"]);
  select2.trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select name="question_tags[]" id="question_tags" class="select2_tags" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```